# Tracing Network Usage from Specific IP Address on Centos 6

Tags: networking, monitoring, centos6, bandwidth

I found this article http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/ but I'm kind of stuck here. I'm running a server with Centos 6.8 64bit for hosting customers. I have about 100 IP addresses routed here and The server is using high consistent bandwidth throughout the day. I'm trying to figure out which specific IP address it's coming from, which user. It appears mostly incoming, probably apache requests but I simply need help to pinpoint which specific user/IP address (both), not just the interface itself.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, is there a question here that we can help you with?

Comment: Always rude responses in this community. Out of hundreds of online forums I've been part of for the last 20 years, no one has ever misunerstood my clear questions except SE here and always sarcastic as if to say you're an idiot and you didn't ask your question right. So unpleasant and childish with marking down the "point" on my topics. This has happened so many times and only here. How much more clearer can it be, or do you love being miserable?I posted the same copy/paste on 2 other tech forums and they gave me a clear answer right off the bat. You? No, always responding stupidly.

Comment: You posted a link to an article which has a huge list of network monitoring tools and then said that you are trying to figure out which IP addresses are accessing your server. We have no access to your server so we cannot say. What has your research into the issue highlighted? Where has your troubleshooting and problem solving lead to? Do you have a specific question about how to use any of the miriad pieces of software that you linked to? ServerFault is not a free network consulting service - what specifically can we help you with?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your requirements are, or what resources you have available, but if I had this problem I would probably use [Packetbeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/packetbeat).

Answer (score 0):

I like using *Wireshark* for this type of work. You can inspect by IP or Packet, or even specific signatures within a packet

https://www.wireshark.org/download.html